# Picture not working on fedora arm on raspberry pi

Tags: fedora, raspberry-pi, arm

I have an issue booting Fedora ARM Version on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+.
I've written the raw image using `dd` it starts booting just fine, i can see the whole kernel boot process.

But when it needs to boot into Desktop, picture gets lost.

Pi is connected to 40' FullHD TV via HDMI cable.
If i connect it to a monitor, also via HDMI cable, it works fine, i get the picture, but not when it's connected to TV.

I've addedd

```
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=16
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
config_hdmi_boost=9 (tried it with 4 as well, and tried with hdmi_boost too)
```

in config.txt, but doesn't work.
Works fine if i boot raspbian on it.

Comment: Many TV have problems with HDMI from computers when resolution is too high. You may try to low-down resolution,  under RealHD or under fake-HD (720p) // some ohter needs exactly the HD resolution no more no less ... depending on your luck ; you may work around that.

Comment: I would suggest, if you have the resources/ability, connecting a laptop to the TV via hdmi and figuring out exactly what settings work on the TV, then try to specify those explicitly on the Pi's config.

Comment: I have tested it with laptop. Same resolution (1080p, 60Hz) works when laptop is connected to TV via HDMI. On laptop i have Fedora 29 and Manjaro. Same config works on Raspbian, though